# Is it possible to take the common multiplier out of the degree bracket? Or do I need to raise it to a degree first?

Tags: linear-algebra

$81-(y^2+6y)^2$

*Can I do this:*  $81-y(y+6)^2$ *?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, and you have the right idea. Let's go step by step.

Remember we have the property $(uv)^n = u^n v^n$ - this is a law of exponents. So that second term is

$$ (y^2 + 6y)^2 = \left[ y (y + 6) \right]^2 = y^2(y+6)^2. $$

Answer (score 0):

No,you can't do that.

$$ (y^2 + 6y)^2 = \left\{ y (y + 6) \right\}^2 = y^2(y+6)^2. $$ [Since,$(pq)^n = p^n q^n$ ]

Or,you can think it in this way:

$ (y^2 + 6y)^2$

= $\left\{ y (y + 6) \right\}^2 $

=$\left\{ y (y + 6) \right\}.\left\{ y (y + 6) \right\}$

=$y^2(y+6)^2. $

So,  $81- (y^2 + 6y)^2$

=$81-y^2(y+6)^2. $